# Accordion add and remove class

Tags: jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a document that you want to activate and deactivate a background of a ul tag.
In my code done so far managed to do, however this active at all. How to Activate possible on what is selected?

This link view code http://jsfiddle.net/bruno_aw/3E6Qw/.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.mais_info').click(function() {  
                if ($('.relacionadas').is(':visible')) {
                    $('.list_calendar .calendar_listing ul').removeClass('bg_cinza');
                } 
                else {
                    $('.list_calendar .calendar_listing ul').addClass('bg_cinza');
                } 
                var id = this.id;
                id =  id.replace('bt_','');
                $('#info_'+id).slideToggle('fast', function(){
                    if ($('#info_'+id).is(':visible')){
                        $('#bt_'+id).css('background-position','left bottom');
                    } else {
                        $('#bt_'+id).css('background-position','left top');
                    }                         
                });                    
            });                 
        });
```

When clicking. Mais_info opens. Related and active in background. List_calendar. Calendar_listing ul but when click 2 the error happens.

Would you like to click and activate each indepente if possible.

Accepted suggestion to improve my code in the form of accordion.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? using `$(this)` will get the one you are selecting

```
$(this).parent().removeClass('bg_cinza');
```

demo here http://jsfiddle.net/3E6Qw/3/

Comment: Ok, good! Thank you!
But my intention is that. List_calendar. Calendar_listing ul when is active with the gray background color too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this: http://jsfiddle.net/3E6Qw/4/

```
 $('.mais_info').click(function() {  
     if ($('.relacionadas').is(':visible')) {
          $('.list_calendar .calendar_listing ul',this).removeClass('bg_cinza');
          $(this).parent().removeClass('bg_cinza');
     } else {
          $('.list_calendar .calendar_listing ul',this).addClass('bg_cinza');
          $(this).parent().addClass('bg_cinza');
     }
```

Comment: Oh sorry for late response just had dinner over here. updated the answer which you were looking for.